# Till when are God of War Saga vouchers valid?

Tags: ps3, god-of-war

God of War saga is a collection of 5 games for the PS3, of which 2 are available through a PSN voucher code. From what I've read, the validity of the vouchers was extended till 3/31/2014 and then 3/31/2016. Have there been any further extensions to this? Some retailers are still selling new copies of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl:dr; I don't know the final expiry date but in my case, a code which was supposed to expire on 3/31/2016 was redeemable on 7/22/2016.

I initially purchased a used copy from GameStop with the expiry date 3/31/2016 but I received an ambiguous error (it did not say that code has been redeemed) so I presumed it had expired.

I returned the GameStop copy and bought a new one from Amazon. While it has the same expiry date, I didn't have any issues redeeming the code.